# Tokenize2 in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, tokenize2

I want to use [Tokenize2](https://github.com/zellerda/Tokenize2) in `node.js` (`commonjs`).

but `const tokenize2 = require('./scripts/tokenize2.js');` does not work.

Can anyone help me how to use it in `node.js`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where and how you've called the script, looking here: https://zellerda.github.io/Tokenize2/ it claims that the file (when compiled) is called: tokenize2.min.js

So perhaps you should try:

```
const tokenize2 = require('./scripts/tokenize2.min.js');
```